# Under what circumstances is jQuery's document.ready() not required?

Tags: jquery

While John Resig's recommendation is, quite rightly, to declare all events within a `jquery.document.ready()` function, I know that you don't actually *have* to put everything in there.  In fact, there are cases where it may be more appropriate to deliberately put methods outside of the ready event.

But what are those cases?  Obviously best practice dictates that all events are declared within the ready event, so what would best practice be for declarations outside that event?

**Edit**
Remember, I'm not just after the less-obvious stuff, but I'd like to get a good account of the obvious parts as well.  For example, if I'm writing a plugin, I wouldn't encapsulate that code in a `jquery.document.ready()` call.

Comment: Could you give a link to that recommendation? I'd like to read it. Thank you!

Comment: @RoTo not sure whether this is what Phil is referring to but still good reading: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29 (URL gets garbled, you'll need to copy+paste)

Comment: @RoToRa http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

Comment: Sure.  http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put everything in jquery.document.ready() which:

- changes layout (you want to prevent page-flicker)
- is needed for user-interaction, to make the page usable

What can postponed is:

- everything not important for the user, for example analytics, ads
- things (slightly) improving the user experience
- fetching non-essential widgets or buttons to be added to the page

Comment: @Pekka's answer is quite right and, while it has been well-voted, I personally think this answer better satisfies what I'm actually asking.

Answer (score 5):

Putting things into the `ready` event makes sure that the full DOM is available at the time the function is called.

Any functions and events not depending on the DOM don't need to be put into the `ready` event.

Sometimes you even need to keep things out of the `ready` function, e.g. `document.write()` commands that are supposed to place HTML into the markup at the position the script is at.

Comment: DON'T use document.write() ! :p

Comment: @jAndy good point, but if you *want* to use it, you need to do so outside the event. :)