# jQuery ready, is it always needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Regarding my question here: [Validate dynamically added control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468616/validate-dynamically-added-control)

Should we always use the ready function on javascripts?

Comment: [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809530/under-what-circumstances-is-jquerys-document-ready-not-required) Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One should *only manipulate the DOM when it is guaranteed that such an operation is valid and behaves in a well-defined manner*.

Delaying execution until the "document ready event" (jQuery.ready) ensures the DOM is "complete". However, depending upon browser and context, it is quite possible it is not needed -- not something I like to bet on (it also involves more thinking and makes code more dependent upon the HTML/code order).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery documentation shows this below:

> All three of the following syntaxes
>   are equivalent:
>
> • $(document).ready(handler)
>
> • $().ready(handler) (this is not
>   recommended)
>
> • $(handler)

Any JQuery starting with $(handler) executes when the DOM is ready. You don't need to worry about the ready bit.

SOURCE: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

No: it is only needed if you need to wait for the DOM to finish loading.

You can also use the "live" function to bind which may decrease page load times as described here
http://encosia.com/2010/08/18/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> The .ready() method is generally
>   incompatible with the 
>   attribute. If load must be used,
>   either do not use .ready() or use
>   jQuery's .load() method to attach load
>   event handlers to the window or to
>   more specific items, like images.

U can Google or search on `SO` for similar answer

Comment: Also read this [Learning jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use document ready. place your jQuery just before `</body>` tag and your other jQuery scripts and plugins after your jQuery as such.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="other.js"></script>
<script>
  $('div').click.....
</script>
</body>
```

There's a great article about this "[don't let document ready slow you down](http://encosia.com/2010/08/18/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/)"

Answer (score 0):

Depends the element your workin on, you have many possibilities.
If it's juste for a navigationbar or a module you can chose different DOM elements.

```
/* for a menu */
$('.menu').ready(function() {...})

/* for the all page */
$(docuement).ready(function() {...})
```

But you can also include your jquery file and your script at the end of page.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.menu').click(function() {...})
</script>
```